# Javascript "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function" when calling event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am working with JS and Webpack and I got the error `"Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function"` when trying to add and event listener.

My code is:

```
import Dom from './js/dom';
import game from './js/game';
import './style/style.css';



const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener('click', game().startGame.bind(this));
```

And in game.js the code is:

```
const game = (() => {
 
//Some code//
const startGame = function startGame() {
    getPlayers();
    gameStatus = true;
    helpers().populateGrid(playerBoard);
    dom().createPlayerBoard(playerBoard);
    helpers().populateGrid(computerBoard);
    dom().createCompBoard(computerBoard);
    dom().displayGame();
  };

  return {getPlayers, setTurn, changeTurn, whosTurn, isWin, whoWon, makeAttack, startGame, getPeg, };
})();

export { game as default};
```

Does anyone know where this code is coming from? I have tried to change the export to non-default and some other thing but I am stuck here
Thanks in advance

Comment: The startGame doesn't seem to be a function

Comment: What function is it complaining about? `startGame` looks fine but your calling dozens of functions in `startGame` it could be any of these. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: `game` is a IIFE so you don't need to invoke it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `()` from

```
const game = (() => {
 
//Some code//

  return {getPlayers, setTurn, changeTurn, whosTurn, isWin, whoWon, makeAttack, startGame, getPeg, };
})(); // <= this part here at the end.
```

Not really able to help if you don't share more code.

Other possibilities could be that

```
const submit = document.getElementById('submit');
```

is not returning what you expect.

OR since you just shared more code, try:

```
const game = (() => {
 
//Some code//
const startGame = function startGame() {
    getPlayers();
    gameStatus = true;
    helpers().populateGrid(playerBoard);
    dom().createPlayerBoard(playerBoard);
    helpers().populateGrid(computerBoard);
    dom().createCompBoard(computerBoard);
    dom().displayGame();
  };

  return {getPlayers, setTurn, changeTurn, whosTurn, isWin, whoWon, makeAttack, startGame, getPeg, };
});

export default game;
```

OR

the issue is with `dom()` could be an object instead of the expected function?

OR
the issue is with `helpers()` could also be an object instead of the expected function

Or any other function you are calling within that function could be an object...

My advice, try debugging it step by step and you will find the faulty object/function

Comment: Thanks, removing ```()``` the event listener fires